# No module named 'ethereum'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a python code that uses the ethereum module. When I use visual stuidio code pip install ethereum to install the module I get the following error ERROR: Could not build wheels for scrypt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Answer (score 0):

The `ethereum` module on pypi links to https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/, which is deprecated. Try https://pypi.org/project/py-evm/